# How do I run a macro in the selenium IDE without having to take my hands off the keyboard?

Tags: automation, ide

I am looking for some form of utility that can be run from the command line in Ubuntu 
that will click a button in a specific window. What I want to do is run a macro in the selenium IDE without having to take my hands off the keyboard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `xdotool` command line utility to create mouse (and keyboard) events.

It is quite versatile, so you probably need to look at [the manual](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool) to find the commands for your particular purpose.

For example, to move the cursor to pixel position 500,500 and click, you would run

```
xdotool mousemove  500 500
xdotool click 1 # 1 is the left button.
```